# Internal Server Error while sending simultaneous calls to springboot oauth2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am facing a issue while sending simultaneous calls to spring boot application.Some requests return access token successfully while others give internal server error.I am also not able to find any logs in the application related to this.

configure method looks like this:

```java
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient(clientId).secret(secretKey)
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token").scopes("read","write")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "USER","ADMIN")
        .autoApprove(true)
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(500);
    }
```

Comment: which strategy have you used to store tokes?? i.e how have you implemented token store?

Comment: usually if you store token in database like mysql you may see this type of error, so it is recommended to configure redis token store.

Comment: this is my token store method 
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
     readPropertyFile();
  final JdbcTokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(databaseUrl)
    .username(dbUserName).password(dbPassword).driverClassName(dbDriverClass).build());
        /*return new JdbcTokenStore(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(databaseUrl)
    .username(dbUserName).password(dbPassword).driverClassName(dbDriverClass).build());*/
  tokenStore.setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(new EnhancedAuthenticationKeyGenerator());
  return tokenStore;
    }